# Printing range with concatenation

Tags: python, awk

Extracting into single string

```
Number 1:  
Number 2:  55-60(a)
Number 3:  43/32455, 225(c), 26/10533-10541
Number 4:  234(b) 
Number 5:  
Number 6:  643/54231 
Number 7:  10(a), 162(b) 
Number 8:  742/12345,12346
(c=cross,b=bold,a=alpha)
```

The Number with value (digit) which is "Number 4" will be the 234c**4**
etc:

```
Number 4:  234(b) 

"4" or any digit with Number [0-9], will be concatenated with c = c + 4
234 is the value for the Number 4, then 234 + c4 = 234c4 (flagged as b = bold)


Number 6:  643/54231 
value without any flag will be sorted into the cross column along with cross tag (c)

Sorted : 
cross
43c3@SP32455;225c3;643c6@SP54231
```

Print range

```
Number 2: 55-60(a)
Sorted :
alpha
55c2;56c2;57c2;58c2;59c2;60c2

Number 3:  26/10533-10541
cross
26c3@SP10533;26c3@SP10534;26c3@SP10535;26c3@SP10536;26c3@SP10537;26c3@SP10538;26c3@SP10539;26c3@SP10540;26c3@SP10541
```

Once all flagged output(alpha,bold,cross/a,b,c) has been listed.
etc:

```
a / alpha =
55c2;56c2;57c2;58c2;59c2;60c2;10c7
b / bold = 
234c4;162c7
c / cross = 
43c3@SP32455;225c3;26c3@SP10533;26c3@SP10534;26c3@SP10535;26c3@SP10536;26c3@SP10537;26c3@SP10538;26c3@SP10539;26c3@SP10540;26c3@SP10541;643c6@SP54231;742c8@SP12345;742c8@SP12346
```

It will combined into one-line as expected output (comma-separated), below

```
a,b,c
55c2;56c2;57c2;58c2;59c2;60c2;10c7,234c4;162c7,43c3@SP32455;225c3;26c3@SP10533;26c3@SP10534;26c3@SP10535;26c3@SP10536;26c3@SP10537;26c3@SP10538;26c3@SP10539;26c3@SP10540;26c3@SP10541;643c6@SP54231;742c8@SP12345;742c8@SP12346
```

Breakdown for crosscheck purpose:

```
alpha
55c2;56c2;57c2;58c2;59c2;60c2;10c7
bold
234c4;162c7
cross
43c3@SP32455;225c3;26c3@SP10533;26c3@SP10534;26c3@SP10535;26c3@SP10536;26c3@SP10537;26c3@SP10538;26c3@SP10539;26c3@SP10540;26c3@SP10541;643c6@SP54231;742c8@SP12345;742c8@SP12346
```

For now I'm using one line script for printing range.

```
for a in {10533..10541}; do echo $a | awk '{printf "26c3@SP%s;",$0}'; done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, I'll add my own script, shortly

Comment: @user10254032, Thanks for adding your efforts in your question but your sample input and expected sample output is not clear, please do add more clear explanation of getting expected output in your question, thank you.

Comment: thanks for looking into this, I've edited the following questions

Comment: @user10254032, could you please elaborate on how `234c4` is getting generated, logic wise please, thank you.

Comment: 234 c 4 
(234 is taken from the = 234(b)) (c is contant string) (4 is taken from the string of "Number (4)")
Number 4 : 234 (b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in pure awk. It is not particularly readable and I am not convinced that awk is the right tool for the job in this particular case. Maybe some patterns and/or actions may have to be adapted. I based the solution on your particular sample case.

```
BEGIN { RS = "\n|, |:  " }

$1 ~ /^Number/                 { sub(":", "", $2); current = $2 }
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+-[0-9]+\(a\)$/    { sub(/\(a\)$/, "", $1);
                                 split($1, a, "-")
                                 for (i=a[1]; i <= a[2]; i++)
                                   alpha = alpha (alpha == "" ? "" : ";") sprintf("%dc%d", i, current)
                               }
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+\(a\)$/           { sub(/\(a\)$/, "", $1)
                                 alpha = alpha (alpha == "" ? "" : ";") sprintf("%dc%d", $1, current)
                               }
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+\(b\)$/           { sub(/\(a\)$/, "", $1)
                                 bold = bold (bold == "" ? "" : ";") sprintf("%dc%d", $1, current)
                               }
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$/        { split($1, a, "/")
                                 cross = cross (cross == "" ? "" : ";") sprintf("%dc%d@SP%d", a[1], current, a[2])
                               }
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+\/[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/ { split($1, a, "[/-]")
                                 for (i=a[2]; i <= a[3]; i++)
                                   cross = cross (cross == "" ? "" : ";") sprintf("%dc%d@SP%d", a[1], current, i)
                               }
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+\/[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/ { n = split($1, a, "[/,]");
                                 for (i=2; i <= n; i++)
                                   cross = cross (cross == "" ? "" : ";") sprintf("%dc%d@SP%d", a[1], current, a[i])
                               }

END { print "alpha"; print alpha ; print "bold" ; print bold ; print "cross" ; print cross }
```